# Error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 13: did not find expected key

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-service

I am trying to deploy this yaml to create a service for 6 different grok-exporters deployment and I have this error below whenever I try to deploy this manifest:

```
error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 13: did not find expected key and i can't figure out the issue
```

The yaml Manifest:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: grok-exporter-centralized-service
spec:
    type: ClusterIP
    ports:
    - name: cluster-autoscaler-grok-exporter-metrics
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9144
      port: 9148
    selector:
      app: cluster-autoscaler-grok-exporter
    - name: evicted-pods-grok-exporter
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9144
      port: 9149
    selector:
      app: evicted-pods-grok-exporter
    - name: flux-hr-grok-exporter
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9144
      port: 9144
    selector:
      app: flux-hr-grok-exporter
    - name: flux-system-grok-exporter
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9144
      port: 9145
    selector:
      app: flux-system-grok-exporter
    - name: ha-proxy-grok-exporter
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9144
      port: 9146
    selector:
      app: ha-proxy-grok-exporter
    - name: spot-requests-grok-exporter
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9144
      port: 9147
    selector:
      app: spot-requests-grok-exporter
```

I checked the similar issues here but unfortunately, I couldn't get this script working, so I really appreciate the assistance.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you have some `spec.selector.app` after each `spec.ports`. There should be only one selector, the ports array should list all ports with no interruption

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: grok-exporter-centralized-service
spec:
    type: ClusterIP
    ports:
    - name: cluster-autoscaler-grok-exporter-metrics
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9144
      port: 9148
    - name: evicted-pods-grok-exporter
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9144
      port: 9149
    - name: flux-hr-grok-exporter
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9144
      port: 9144
    - name: flux-system-grok-exporter
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9144
      port: 9145
    - name: ha-proxy-grok-exporter
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9144
      port: 9146
    - name: spot-requests-grok-exporter
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9144
      port: 9147
    selector:
      app: spot-requests-grok-exporter
```

---

Second take: assuming that we want a single service pointing to several exporters, driven by distinct deployments. And that all those exporters would listen on the same port, `9144`.

In addition to the current labels configured on your deployments, we would add a new one, shared between all those exporters / deployments. Say `foo=bar`.

Now, I can create a single "exporter" service, whose endpoints would target all my exporter ports:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: generic-exporter
spec:
    type: ClusterIP
    ports:
    - name: generic-exporter
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9144
      port: 9144
    selector:
      foo: bar
```

Comment: this is correct, there should be only one selector.

Comment: but each of these ports below to a different deployment.. if i took the selector out of the port , how can i associate each port with its deployment ?

Comment: You can not. A service has a single combination of selectors. If you have different set of labels to route traffic to, then you need different Services as well.

Comment: does it mean that i can't use a single service for multiple deployments?

Comment: A Service matches a combination of labels. In theory, they could target Pods affiliated to different deployments, statefulsets, ... if this is what you mean to do. Now, if that set of labels is meant to change, then you need additional services. If you're shipping a bunch of exporters, you might want to regroup them into a single Pod, if you want them all behind a single service. Otherwise, there's nothing wrong in creating several Services, pointing to different stuff

Comment: Here's another take on it: instead of translating ports, use a single entry in your ports array (9144 -> 9144), and try to match a new label. Something like `podtype=exporter` or whatever. Make sure all your exporter Pods come with that label.

Comment: i labeled all of them with one label and it worked.. the issue right now is with port-forwarding i get : error: time out waiting for the condition.. do you have a clue ?

Comment: Do you mean you're using something like `kubectl port-forward service/your-service 9144:9144`, and you get that timeout error? Unsure. If you do some `kubectl get endpoints -n namespace your-service-name`, can you see your Service Endpoints / your Pods IP addresses in the SDN? If so, from a node in your cluster, any troubles running `curl http://your-service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local:9144`? What if you curl each Pod IP address directly, are they all up and running?